# Replace string in ArrayList

Tags: java, android

I am string to replace a string in a column ArrayList. I am getting an error on the expression

> `Bad return type in lambda expression: String cannot be converted to Articles`

```
articlesArrayList.replaceAll(articles -> articles.getAuthor().replace("."," "));
```

Comment: What's there in articlesArrayList?

Comment: Share the complete code

Comment: Please post a [mre]. We do not know what articlesArrayList actually is. Although I suspect the problem is that `getAuthor().replace(".", " ")` returns a String, and  `replaceAll()`on an `ArrayList<Articles>` will expect objects of type `Articles`. You might want to do `setAuthor(getAuthor().replace(".", " "))` instead, assuming you implemented the setter.

Comment: are your arrayList contain object of type Articles ?  if yes, you can't put a string at it's place, because it seems that the conversion return a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `replaceAll` method is trying to return an array of articles.  Your function map is returning a string instead.  If you want to replace the '.' character with ' ' for each author, use the `ArrayList.forEach` method instead.

Comment: `articlesArrayList.forEach(article -> article.setAuthor(article.getAuthor().replace("."," ")));`?

Comment: assuming the getter and setter methods are working, that should be correct.

Comment: Thank you so much. Foreach for works. Yes,  getter and setter methods work fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().replace();
    }

    public void replace() {
        List<Article> articlesArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        articlesArrayList.add(Article.builder().author("Sagar.Gangwal").build());
        articlesArrayList.stream().forEach(article -> article.getAuthor().replaceAll(".", " "));

        articlesArrayList = articlesArrayList.stream()
                .map(a -> this.update(a)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(articlesArrayList.get(0));
    }

    private static Article update(Article a) {
        a.author = a.getAuthor().replaceAll("\\.", " ");
        return a;
    }
}
```

You can see above code.

Here i am trying to create stream and then foreach element of that stream i want to update AuthorName with '.' to space.

**`articlesArrayList.stream().map(a -> this.update(a)).collect(Collectors.toList());`**

You need to use stream API and then custom update method to update value.

Also for replacing **`'.'`**, you need to use escape character as well. **`replaceAll`** method of **`String`** class contains first argument as **`regular expression`**.

If you see this , i am escaping **`'.'`** with **`'\\.'`**.
**`a.getAuthor().replaceAll("\\.", " ");`**

So instead of **`replaceAll`**, you can go with replace method which simply take first argument as simply replace one character with passed target character.

You can see difference between [**`replace and replaceAll.`**](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/java-string-replace-replacefirst-replaceall-method-examples/#:%7E:text=The%20difference%20between%20replace(),string%20with%20the%20new%20string.)